# Difference between wss:// and https:// (or ws:// and http://) prefixes when connecting to socket.io server

Tags: sockets, socket.io

I know that we can connect to socket.io server via socket.io-client the following four ways:

1. Using ws:// or wss:// prefix in the URL

```js
const manager = new Manager("ws://localhost:3333/", {
  reconnectionDelayMax: 1000,
});

const socket = manager.socket('/', {
  auth: {
    token
  },
});
```

2. Using http:// or https:// prefix in the URL

```js
const manager = new Manager("http://localhost:3333/", {
  reconnectionDelayMax: 1000,
});

const socket = manager.socket('/', {
  auth: {
    token
  },
});
```

I wonder if there is any difference between connecting to socket.io servers these ways.

Googling it didn't help much. Chat GPT says there are differences. But chat GPT is not the most reliable source of information.

Comment: Wss is for websockets. When an http connection is started, they can include the header “Connection: Upgrade”, which switches to a web socket. Once the server and client agree to switch to a websocket the connection is left open like a normal TCP connection, except with encryption in the case of wss. Websockets stay open, where http requests are one time things. If you use http, you may end up sending a request every time you need to get or post information. This can be inefficient. I may be completely misunderstanding the question which is why this is a comment.

Comment: @SupaMaggie70b I need to know, what is the difference between using `http://` and `ws://`?

Comment: As someone wrote in the comments, http:// is the httpprotocol where ws:// opens an http connection then moves it to a websocket. Websockets are different from standard http connections. A normal http message has a request and a response and they both follow the http format, websockets are stream based and you can send any information at any time without needing to start a new request.

Answer (score 2):

The prefixes wss:// and https:// indicate that the connection is secured using TLS/SSL encryption. The prefixes ws:// and http:// indicate that the connection is not secured.

A HTML page loaded by a browser over HTTP can open both a non-secure (ws) as well as secure (wss) WebSocket connection. However, a HTML page that loads over HTTPS can only open a wss connection (not a ws connection). This is because browsers enforce the same-origin policy for WebSocket connections.

Therefore, if you want to connect to a socket.io server using a secure WebSocket connection, you should use the wss:// prefix and make sure that your server supports TLS/SSL encryption and has a valid certificate. Otherwise, you can use the ws:// prefix for a non-secure WebSocket connection, but be aware of the potential security risks involved.

Comment: But what is the difference between using `ws://` and `http://`?

Comment: Same thing @ibodi